# Expression IIF report rdlc

Tags: expression, reportviewer

How can I make a expression to compare multiple textbox and get a value?

I have this Expression: `=IIF(fields!productformat.Value="Fresh - Skin OFF Loin", "OFF", "")` but I need first to check other textboxes and columns if matches then gives the result.

Imagine:
I have 2 column "Specie" and "Skin" and 2 textboxes (txtSpecie and txtSkin), so first it most check if the txtSpecie is the same with the "Specie" column if yes then check what's the value of the "Skin" if the Skin value = "Skin Off" convert to "Off" if "Skin On" convert to "On"

Comment: Why you dont use a normal if/else construct? IIF(fields!productformat.Value="Fresh - Skin OFF Loin", "OFF", "") is nothing more then If fields!productformat.Value="Fresh - Skin OFF Loin" Then "OFF" ELSE ""

In your case I would really try to do exactly what you write. If txtSpecie = SpeciColumn then If SkinValue = "Skin Off" then "Off" etc.

I am not an Expression or ReportViewer expert. Thats just a normal programming step ;)

Comment: Wow, thanks for the idea, I'll give a try then I'll let you know.